# Is there any way I can get a Schengen visa as a Syrian citizen?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, syrian-citizens

I want to visit a friend who lives in Spain. She will be covering the cost of living and everything; she's willing to send me an invitation letter. as well. However, I have never traveled before and, with the situation I'm in, it's very confusing. Is there any way I can get a Schengen visa in Syria?

Comment: Do you have permanent residence somewhere other than Syria? This would make it much easier to get the visa.

Comment: I do, i live in Saudi Arabia atm but im ending the residency in few months and live in Syria, since my passport is expired and it costs a lot of money to renew it if im not in Syria, i need to get it from there :(

Comment: With Saudi residence about to expire and an expired Syrian passport, application to visit Spain might be refused as it may seem that you're trying to avoid returning to your country (and that, once in Spain, you wouldn't). A passport needs to be valid (and for at least 3 months beyond the intended duration of stay) in order to apply for the visa.

Comment: I agree with @Giorgio; one of the criteria to assess if you are likely to leave Spain is if you have a stable live somewhere else. But so far your "stable live" seems to be in Saudi Arabia and so it is coming to an end, and in Syria you do not have anything or anyone preventing you from living elsewhere (as shown by the fact that you have been residing in Saudi Arabia). You will need to make an strong case of showing your ties to Syria and that you do intend to return.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends. You have to convince the Spanish officials that you are a *genuine* tourist. That means you plan to come, see the sights, **and leave again.**

- They will want to know who pays the trip and why. If it is "a lot of money" for your friend, she has to explain why she will spend it.
- They will want to know what reasons you have to return to Syria. One of the best reasons is a stable and well-paid job. Other ties like owning property or many relatives who do **not** travel with you you can help, too.

Obviously Syria is not very stable right now, and any jobs in Syria are not very stable for the same reason. Think about what reasons you have **not** to overstay, beyond your honesty which is difficult to judge from your application.

Comment: Thank you very much, i know the situation in syria and how other countries see it,  and i do plan to come back of course it's just a visit for a month or so.
another question if you can possibly help, im reading that there's no spanish embassy in syria, its been closed for few years and im wondering if i can get still get the visa? thank you again.

Comment: @Adiga, the services would either be handled by another Schengen embassy/consulate in Syria or by an embassy in a nearby country. I don't know which one it is, perhaps you should check with the embassy in Beirut.

Answer (score 8):

I'm Syrian and I applied for a Schengen visit visa to visit 2 of my friends, one was a greek and the other one was a UAE national getting higher education in Athens. I live in the UAE and I have a stable job and a good salary. My passport was valid and my residency as well and I provided proof that I've never lived in Syria nor was I going to because my residency here is fixed. I was rejected both times out of fear that I was trying to seek asylum. Your case is way more severe with your residency coming to an end in KSA. So I'm guessing it would be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have residency in other country rather than Syria and stable, it will make a difference. Moreover, if you can prove you are really connected to this country, then you have high chances of getting the schengen visa but not 100% guaranteed.

So basically you have to prove you are a genuine traveller and you travelled to other countries before and did not break their visa. I am Syrian living in Egypt. First time I applied for a Schengen I got rejected I think because I did not have any travel history except Syria and Egypt. After travelling to the far east of Asia and coming back, I applied for a Schengen first as a visitor not as a tourism but this time with very strict documents that I am genuine traveller with very detailed documents about my ties to Egypt and I got it approved.

Once you get approved for the first time, It would be very easy to apply again.